# How to bring togther 3 array of data into an iterable array?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a function that retrieve some data from an API. 
I make a total of 3 query, each one of them returning me an array of data.
I would like to join this 3 array into an iterable array of data, where the index 0 of the new array is the first array, index 1 the second and index 2 the third.
How can I do this?

```
//I have tried to do this, but it returns me an error.
this.serviceAffaire.getAffairesByServiceAndOperateur(this.servEnCours, this.opeEnCours).pipe(
        affaires =>
          forkJoin(
            this.serviceAffaire.getAffairesByServiceAndOperateurAleas(this.servEnCours, this.opeEnCours),
            this.serviceAffaire.getAffairesByServiceAndOperateurUrgent(this.servEnCours, this.opeEnCours),
          ).pipe(
            map(([affairesAleas, affairesUrgent]) => [affairesAleas, affairesUrgent])
          )
      ).subscribe((data : [Affaire, Affaire, Affaire][]) => {
        for(let d of data){
          for(let n of d[0])
           //I have an error in the for condition, saying Type Affaire must have a Symbole.iterator method that returns an iterator. 
        }
      })
```

Comment: Firstly, your Observable only returns an Array of two Arrays. Try putting all three method calls inside your `forkJoin`. Next, your `map` isn't doing anything. Finally, if each Observable emits an Array, the type you're declaring for the `subscribe` callback is wrong. I believe what you want is `Affaire[][]`, as in an array of `Affaire` arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below solution. `forkJoin` will produce an array of the three response i.e `Affaire[][]`, all you need to do is to `flat()` them as one dimensional array

```
forkJoin(
this.serviceAffaire.getAffairesByServiceAndOperateurAleas(this.servEnCours, this.opeEnCours),
this.serviceAffaire.getAffairesByServiceAndOperateur(this.servEnCours, this.opeEnCours),
this.serviceAffaire.getAffairesByServiceAndOperateurUrgent(this.servEnCours, this.opeEnCours))
.pipe(map(arr=>[...arr[0],...arr[1],...arr[2]])).subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it returns me an error saying that flat does not exist on type [Affaire[], Affaire[], Affaire[]]. Maybe I do something wrong in my service ?

Comment: try this map(arr=>[...arr[0],...arr[1],...arr[2]]) 
updated the answer. Or you can try to log the arr first and check the data structure.